# std::decay and removing const qualifiers

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, types, type-traits

I'm trying to understand the workings of std::decay a little better. Per cppreference it's supposed to remove const and volatile classification from the type as part of other transformations it does. However, below function displays "False", "True" vs. "True", "True" as one might expect. Can someone please clarify why the const is needed when matching against the decayed type here?

```
int main()
{
   const char *p = "testing";
   cout << "------------------" << endl;
   cout << boolalpha << is_same<char *, decay_t<decltype(p)>>::value << endl;
   cout << boolalpha << is_same<const char *, decay_t<decltype(p)>>::value << endl;
   cout << "------------------" << endl;
}
```

Comment: It only removes a top-level constness. `const char *` itself is not actually const at the top level (it's a pointer **to** const `char`, but the pointer itself is not const). On the other hand, `char *const` *is* const, and would become `char *`. Similarly, `const char *const` would become `const char *`.

Comment: I reckon the TS also needs to know a workaround to remove the const from the pointed-to type. (I do). To produce char*. Any ideas?

Comment: Using the following partial template specialization:
```
template <typename T>
struct remove_const {
    static_assert(false, "not chosen");
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
struct remove_const<const T*> {
    using type = T*;
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::decay_t` would remove the `const` from the pointer, had it been `const`, not the type it's pointing at.

That is, a `char* const` would decay into a `char*`.